# Router with ability to introduce manual latency to a device?

Tags: wifi, wireless, router, wlan

I'm searching for a router that has capabilities to add manual latency to a device in my network (for example, add 10ms of ping to a random device on my network). What router should I buy?

EDIT: I found that dd-wrt routers have the "tc" command that may help with this, but I also saw people that said that doesn't work, I just don't want to waste money on something that may not work.

Comment: But why tho? Generally this would be something controlled on the device end, not the router.

Comment: It's for online gaming, the game I'm playing punishes good internet connection and you get a disadvantage compared to high ping players. I tested and the game performs way better on my 3G Phone Hotspot than my home internet via ethernet.

Comment: Sounds strange. What game is this? Also I believe a software solution will be easier to implement than a hardware level one. Try looking at this [Stack Overflow question on how to create low bandwidth, high latency environments intended for software testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130354/how-do-i-simulate-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-environment).

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer, the issue is that is a console game called Splatoon 2, since it it's p2p and has no lag compensation you will always have a disvantage over a high latency opponent (people would one-shoot you, kill behind walls, etc).
That's why I'm searching a hardware solution, if it were a PC game then the link you provided me would work.